# laravel livewire $wire is not defined

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-livewire

I think I have all my imports right, but I'm getting a `$wire is not defined` error.

This is at the bottom of my master layout blade file:

```
@livewireScripts

<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
 
@stack('plugin-scripts')

@stack('custom-scripts')
```

In my livewire component I have this:

```
@push('custom-scripts')
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            console.log($wire.find($('#my-div').attr('id')));
        });
    </script>
@endpush
```

I was reading that $wire is an Alpine directive, and here's where I'm including Alpine. I can also type Alpine in the console and it is registered, so I believe that's working.

in my bootstrap.js:

```
import Alpine from 'alpinejs'

window.Alpine = Alpine

window.Alpine.start()
```

Also if I type Livewire in the console, it returns the Livewire object, so that seems to be getting loaded correctly as well. However, I added this bit to my code and it did nothing:

```
  document.addEventListener('livewire:load', function() {
      console.log('livewire loaded'); // Your JS here.
  });
```

Comment: `$(document).ready(function() {` won't work, because `livewire:load` hasn't finished yet. (You also probably don't need jQuery at all here.)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old topic but for anyone who stumbles on this.
Try calling `window.Livewire.start()` before `Alpine.start()`

Like so:

```
if (window.Livewire) {
    window.Livewire.start();
}

Alpine.start();
```